# What's the difference between Query and Import requests?

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Using the QuickBooks PHP DevKit, I noticed there are many types of requests, and most of them map to specific requests in the qbXML API. However, two requests stand out, and I'm not sure what the difference is. Here's an example:

```
QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_INVOICE
QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_INVOICE
```

And another

```
QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_DELETEDTXNS
QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_DELETEDTXNS
```

What's the difference between these two? They map to `InvoiceQuery` and `TxnDeletedQuery` in qbXML respectively ... so why differentiate them?

Comment: the `priorityForAction` function in the `QuickBooks_Utilities` class on line 738 I guess might answer the question in part: `Query` is higher on the priority list than `Import`, so if both `InvoiceQuery` and `InvoiceImport` are in the queue the `Query` will happen first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just provided as convenience constants if you need to distinguish between mass importing data, and querying for a specific record/set of records.

For example, consider a scenario where you are doing a full two-way sync of QuickBooks customers with your app -- whenever something changes in QuickBooks, you grab the change, and whenever something changes in your app, you push the change to QuickBooks.

This requires you to be able to:

1. Poll QuickBooks every so often for everything that changes ("import" data from QuickBooks)
2. To modify a customer in QuickBooks, you first need to query for that individual customer to get the latest QuickBooks `EditSequence` value ("query" for that specific customer to get that `EditSequence`)

So we provide two separate constants for convenience so that you can distinguish these two different types of requests from each other.

Realize that all of the constants are just there for convenience -- it doesn't really matter what value/constant you use, *as long as what you have in $map matches what you queue up with `$Queue->enqueue($action, $id, ...)`*. For example, this will work just fine too:

```
$map = array(
   'YourMommyWearsArmyBoots' => array( 'your_request_callback', 'your_response_callback' )
  );

...

$Queue->enqueue('YourMommyWearsArmyBoots', $id);
```

All the framework does is matches up the `$action` parameter to `->enqueue(...)` to the corresponding key in `$map`.

Comment: Good to know! And if I haven't said it before, thank you and great job on the devkit :)